# How to click through googlemap pins

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I have a map using Xamarin.Forms.Googlemap in my xamarin forms app.
Is there a way to click on what is behind a pin?

I am creating polygons on the googlemap and then adding custom pins with orchard names on it.

```
 Pin pin = new Pin()
 {
     Icon = CreateLabels(orchardname, 60),
     Flat = true,
     Address = string.Empty,
     Label = string.Empty,

     Position = Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Bounds.FromPositions(allpositions).Center,
     Anchor = new Point(0.5, -1),

     IsVisible = _showPropertyzoom

};

  protected BitmapDescriptor CreateLabels(string Text, int size)
    {

        SKBitmap bitmap;
        SKCanvas bitmapCanvas;
        SKColor white = new SKColor(255,255,255);
        SKColor blue = new SKColor(0,88,164);

        SKPaint textPaintStroke = new SKPaint { TextSize = size, StrokeWidth=3, Color = white, FakeBoldText=true, Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke};
        SKPaint textPaint = new SKPaint { TextSize = size, Color = blue };


        SKRect bounds = new SKRect();
        textPaint.MeasureText(Text, ref bounds);

        bitmap = new SKBitmap((int)(bounds.Right + 10), (int)(bounds.Height +5));
        using (bitmapCanvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap))
        {
            bitmapCanvas.Clear();

            bitmapCanvas.DrawText(Text, bounds.Left, -bounds.Top, textPaintStroke);
            bitmapCanvas.DrawText(Text, bounds.Left, -bounds.Top, textPaint);
        }


        SKData data = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap).Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
        var image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromStream(data.AsStream());
        return image;


    }
```

The problem i am having is when i click on a polygon to trigger the polygonclicked event i am clicking on the pin so nothing happens.

I can't just use the pinclicked event to trigger the polygonclicked event in this case, because the pin/label can span across multiple polygons.

Comment: You can have a conditional statement on your pinclicked event. It would first scan on the map if it's on a polyon then would have to trigger that instead of the pinclicked. Regarding this "because the pin/label can span across multiple polygons." If it is what I think it is then you would still have this problem even if you can click beyond the pin.

Comment: Thanks @javachipper to clarify the labels are so large there can be multiple polygons behind it, so I can't use the pin clicked event because i would not know what polygon that click relates to.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? by label you mean the infowindow of the pin?

Comment: No it did not I am afraid. and not the infowindow the image on the pin itself.

Comment: Have you tried modifying their z-indexes?